# Plotting satellite data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, satellite

I have two data frames with satellite data that I need to plot. The plot I've got so far looks like this: [image]

However I want to get something like this :
[image]

Meaning that I need all data points to have a realistic size relative to longitude and latitude.
CloudSat datapoint size is 1.4 km across track, and 1.7 along track. Amsre datapoint is 4 km across track, and 6 km along track.
The code I use to plot data:

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,15)

ax = cloudsat.plot(kind='scatter', x='Longitude', y='Latitude', color='DarkBlue', label='Cloudsat')

amsre.plot(kind='scatter', x='Longitude', y='Latitude', color='DarkGreen', label='Amsre', ax=ax)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would have expected that the observed and expected result have much more in common.

Comment: Would you show a bit of the `cloudsat` and `amsre` dataframes?